# Is there a way to increment the max number of indexes for appengine app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an appengine app that needs more than 200 indexes for the datastore. What can I do to increment that number like up to 500?

Thank you very much?

Comment: The only way would be to contact support, but as far as I know, it won't happen. They are reluctant to increase number of indexes past 200, since normally it will incur more costs for each write.

Comment: Cost is not relevant. Google already charges each index write

Comment: @ZigMandel I'm just paraphrasing what was said when I requested my own increase ;). They seem to have a lot more metrics internally to take into account (like how many kinds your indexes are spread accross, the size of each index, etc), but the pushback I got since I didn't have enough kinds to spread my indexes across was that it would drive cost and write latency up.

Comment: Yea i was thinking that after i commented. What you mean is that per-write cost would increase on google side. Makes sense.